# Django ImageField will not display on webpage

Tags: python, html, django, model, imagefield

I am using an imageField in my Django model and the photo is not being recognized when I try to display it in the html.

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

class LatestRelease(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='personal/static/img/')
    display = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Here is view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from personal.models import LatestRelease

def index(request):
    releases = LatestRelease.objects.all()
    return render(request, "personal/home.html", {'releases': releases})
```

HTML code

```
 {% for release in releases %}
    <img src="{{ release.cover.url }}" class='' height='235' width='235'>
 {% endfor %}
```

So basically, the image path `{{ release.cover.url }}` is `/personal/static/img/[image name]`
and my photos only appear to show up when I use the url path `/static/img/[image name]` as the source.

Is there anyway to take `/personal` out of the string that is created from `{{ release.cover.url }}` ? Or to make it so that my img source accepts files under `/personal/static/img/[image name]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might help if you showed your settings.py and urls.py files too but I'm guessing that your
development server is not set up to serve that `personal/static/img/[image name]` file. To set that up you need to adjust your settings.py and main project urls.py files.

**settings.py:**

```
# Add these
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

`MEDIA_ROOT` indicates where files can be served from when your `MEDIA_URL` is hit (like when your browser asks for that picture). To actually serve the files you need to set up a view, there is a built-in helper function for serving this files in development, add this to your main project urls.py file

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    # your other views
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Then you should just upload the picture again, it will be saved in `media/<upload_to>/<picturename>`, in your case `media/personal/static/img/<picture_name>`. And your server will actually know
where to find it now.

Check out the 
[documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) for a little better example.

#### P.S.

The hard-coded url that you used, `/static/img/[image name]` worked because the Django development server can, by default, serve static files from the `static/` directory in the project root as well as any `static/` folders in the application root directories. So it was a kind of happy coincidence that your `upload_to` arguement in your ImageField created that `/personal/static/` folder. Then since `DEBUG = True` was set in settings.py you were setup to serve it automatically. This is described (better) in the linked documentation above.

Comment: Thank you this worked and it was very helpful in understanding!

Comment: Cool, glad it helped.