# Django won't serve an image from MEDIA_URL

Tags: python, django

A beginner building a personal blog. Got a simple model with an ImageField. No matter what I try the Django won't serve an image.

Judging by the console output in the Dev Tools it is looking for an image in the wrong folder. I don't know how to fix that. I tried setting up MEDIA_URL, MEDIA_ROOT and adding a urlpattern like it's being suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563454/django-imagefield-upload-to-path/34563512) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452687/django-imagefield-will-not-display-on-webpage/52452722)

I have uploaded the picture via admin panel, its location is media/images/stockmarket.jpg. But for some reason the server is looking for an image here /blog/images/stockmarket.jpg

Project name: 'wikb', 'blog' is an App:
[project_file_system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmx1n.png)

models.py

```py
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Post Title', max_length=200)
    preview = models.CharField('Post Preview', max_length=400)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField('Post Picture', upload_to='images/', blank=True)
```

view.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Post

def home(request):
    all_posts = Post.objects.all()
    hero_post = all_posts[0]
    context = {'hero_post': hero_post, 'all_posts': all_posts}
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context=context)
```

HTML

```
<div class="hero">
    <a href="#" class="hero__link" style="background-image: url({{hero_post.thumbnail}})">
        <article class="hero__article">
            <h2 class="hero__heading">{{hero_post.title}}</h2>
            <p class="hero__preview">{{hero_post.preview}}</p>
        </article>
    </a>
</div>
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

Global urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

It's my first Django project, please explain like I'm 5.

**Update**: I forgot to add .url when I referenced an object in templates.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: only this one: 
[13/Sep/2019 14:04:11] "GET /blog/media/images/stockmarket.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2314
Not Found: /blog/images/stockmarket.jpg

Comment: I believe you URL should be `/media/...` not `/blog/media/...`

Comment: You assigned two `upload_to` parameters in `ImageField` why ?

Comment: Yes. But that's what django is trying to serve and I don't know how to change that.

Comment: Add `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` in blog `urls.py` not the global, that will work

Comment: @Moha369 That `static` expression is already there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In templates, you'll want to use [`.url`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ea25bdc2b94466bb1563000bf81628dea4d80612/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L59-L62) to get the real URL of a [`FieldFile`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ea25bdc2b94466bb1563000bf81628dea4d80612/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L14) (the file contained by a [`FileField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ea25bdc2b94466bb1563000bf81628dea4d80612/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L216) or [`ImageField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ea25bdc2b94466bb1563000bf81628dea4d80612/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L358)):

```
<a href="#" class="hero__link" style="background-image: url({{ hero_post.thumbnail.url }})">
```