# How to access individual fields with of customised User model using AbstractUser?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-context

I have defined a user model inheriting `AbstractUser` from `django.auth.models`. How can I refer to each individual fields of that customized user model? Say if I want to refer to date of birth of the customised user what should I write? I need to show the user profile, so in `show_profile.html` file, I wrote :

```
first name = {{ settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.first_name }}
date 0f birth = {{ settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.dob }}
```

But it didn't work. Any idea?
Moreover, my url route looks like this:

```
path('my-profile/', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='my_profile'),
```

The concerned line in base.html is:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'my_profile' %}">Edit profile</a>
```

The concerned lines in views.py are:

```
class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'show_profile.html'
```

Please tell where I have done wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to display on your `show_profile.html` with `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`?

Comment: show_profile.html shows the profile of the user.

Comment: Some lines in show_profile.html are: first name = {{ settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.first_name }}
date 0f birth = {{ settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.dob }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't access current user information like that, because it is wrong. What you're actually getting with `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` is the model class not the object instance of the current user. You shuld access it through the `request` object via Django's context processors.

On your `settings.py` you should have something like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                ...
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Make sure you have `django.template.context_processors.request` there, and then to access the current user information you just need to use like this:

```
first name = {{ request.user.first_name }}
date 0f birth = {{ request.user.dob }}
```

Comment: Ok got this. but what should I write in the urls.py file? I wrote : path('my-profile/<int:pk>/', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='my_profile'). Is this ok. Again the link to go the profile page is written as: <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'my_profile'/CustomUser.pk %}">Edit profile</a>. Is this ok too. Please advise.

Comment: @SandipNath you should use the name of the url path and include its namespace if necessary `{% url 'my_profile' request.user.pk %}`, if there is some confusion, check [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

Comment: @SandipNath Glad I could help! If there's something else I can help just ping! Consider upvoting if you think it's a good answer ;D

Comment: Many many thanks Bernardo. But a small problem still lies there and that is by writing request.user.picture in the template file, the filename of the picture is displayed, not the picture itself. How the picture, not it's name can be shown?

Comment: @SandipNath How are you currently displaying the picture?

Comment: @SandipNath I believe your problem could be solved by an already answered question here on so check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52452722/7395911)